# how to fetch SMART attributes in SSD?

Tags: disk, ssd, smartctl

I have a SAS SSD and I want to know few things like "Perc_Lifetime_Remain", etc. In the exisiting SATA SSD drive, we are fetching these info by using smartctl tool ("smartctl -A diskname"). But the same command when executed in my new SAS SSD, doesn't give any info of these attributes.

Can anyone let me know, how does smartctl command works?, Will it work only with SATA drives and not with SAS drives? Does the output varies according to the different vendors disks like STEC,MICRON,HITACHI,TOSHIBA?
How to get these attributes in SAS SSD?

Comment: What SAS controller are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the current development version of [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/).  If your disk is still not supported, there is a procedure described somewhere on their site for collecting the SMART parameters of your drive and sending them to the developers.  If you send them these parameters they might add support for your disk at some point.  Beware that playing with these parameters yourself **can** result in permanent damage to your disk.